# Tengo varias facturas que realizo un json desde SQL 2017, pero tengo un problema en la estructura

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, windows-forms, sql-server-2017

Genero mi JSON desde SQL 2017 la cual genera esta estructura tomado desde los una tabla.

```
"detalle": [{
        "numero": "1",
        "codigo": [{
            "tipo": "04",
            "codigo": "593"
        }, {
            "tipo": "04",
            "codigo": "12"
        }],
        "cantidad": "1.000",
        "unidad_medida": "Unid",
        "detalle": "Tour Manglar",
        "precio_unitario": "65435.00000",
        "monto_total": "65435.00000",
        "subtotal": "65435.00000",
        "impuestos": [{
            "codigo": "",
            "tarifa": "0.00",
            "monto": "0.00000"
        }, {
            "codigo": "01",
            "tarifa": "13.00",
            "monto": "73.97000"
        }, {}],
        "montototallinea": "65435.00000"
    }
--------------------------------
pero me gustaria tenerlo asi


"detalle": [{
        "numero": "1",
        "codigo": [{
            "tipo": "04",
            "codigo": "593"
        }],
        "cantidad": "1.000",
        "unidad_medida": "Unid",
        "detalle": "Tour Manglar",
        "precio_unitario": "65435.00000",
        "monto_total": "65435.00000",
        "subtotal": "65435.00000",
        "impuestos": [{
            "codigo": "",
            "tarifa": "0.00",
            "monto": "0.00000"
             }],
        "montototallinea": "65435.00000"
    }
```

Comment: cual es la diferencia ? solo veo que has quitado un item del array de codigo. Como generas ese json, porque si viene de sql podrias aplicar un filtro en la consulta para limitar los datos que luego se exportan al json y que ese codigo no aparezca

Comment: claro, te comento que lo realizo desde sql 2017 donde genero el json. hago un llamado a la table"facturas " donde busco la factura principal y selecciono todos las lineas pero dentro de cada linea van a ver nodo que es donde tengo problema.